# 301 redirects for individual URLs and all other to home

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

How can I set individual URLs via 301 redirect in the htaccess and redirect all other URLs that do not have a 301 to the home page?

Comment: Where are you redirecting the individual URL?  To some external site?  If you are redirecting them internally, do you need to reserve the target URLs not to get redirected?

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow.  Please [edit] the question to address the points that need to be clarified, then re-ask it on [webmasters.se] and delete it here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you simply implement one 301 redirection per URL you want to get redirected. Then below you implement a single catch all rule to rewrite or redirect everything else to whatever you consider your "home page". So first the exceptions, then the general rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?path/one https://example.com/path/A [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?path/two https://example.com/path/B [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?path/tre https://example.com/path/C [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [END]
```

Of course this is only a rough pointer into the right direction, you have to adapt it to your specific situation we do not know.